# Pluggable Signers for Married Wallet

Tags: multi-signature, risk-mitigation

I would like to start a Wallet Protection Service, but simply add myself as a signatory to wallets using the Married Wallets standard.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitcoinj/Uxl-z40OLuQ

I have looked at the design documents, but I cannot find a good how-to for creating Pluggable Signers for a Married Wallet.

Has anyone done this, that might be willing to offer a brief summary?